# Trying to install Sean Corfield's scripting for ColdFusion project, getting class not found errors

Tags: java, scripting, coldfusion

Hi I'm trying to install this tool 'Sean Corfield's scripting for ColdFusion project.' on my server - problem is I am getting "Class not found: com.caucho.quercus.script.QuercusScriptEngineFactory "  errors, I have java 1.6 installed.... I'm not sure how where to get these extra classes ... any help?

[opensuse 11 system, CF8 java 1.6]

-thanks
-sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the installation instructions for the cfphp, as per the "example.cfm" page:

```
Installation:

1. Copy lib/quercus.jar and lib/resin-util.jar to WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/
   (multiserver) or coldfusion8/lib (standalone)
2. Restart ColdFusion 8.
3. Optionally copy customtags/php.cfm into your custom tags path.
```

The important thing is that the quercus.jar is accessible to the JVM.  Your error message indicates that the JVM can't find the jar.

Comment: Edward; I did not. I never got further than the index.cfm, a classic case of me not reading the full docs [though to be fair the documentation wiki is 'under construction'] thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a bit of digging to find that snippet.  Good to hear its working for you!